# can we use "can", "could", "may" & "might" to ask for suggestions"?

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

**Note**: make sure you distinguish "**make suggestions**" & "**ask for suggestions**"

> -make suggestions: eg: *you could stay at home if it rains*
>
> -ask for suggestion: eg: "*Where shall I put the vegetables?*"

It seems that some resources say "[we use ***shall* or *should*** to ask for suggestions, but not ***can*, *could*, *might* or *may***](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7qxm9ePjlU4J:random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/04/modal-verbs-overview.html%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=vn)"

Eg:

*What shall I do with these boxes?*

*Where should I put the vegetables?*

But, this dictionary talks about ["**could**"](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/could)

> **Could**: used in speech to make a polite request or suggestion .... “Where can I stay?” “Well, you could always stay with me.”

They say "**could** to make suggestions" & they don't say "**could** to ask for suggestions"

We can use "**could**" to make suggestions, eg: *you could try glue if tape doesn't work*

So, in this example

> A: “Where can I stay?”
>
> B: “Well, you could always stay with me.”

**could** in "*you could always stay with me.*” make a suggestion, but see the “**Where can I stay?**”, it seems that **can** in this case is asking  for a suggestion.

My question is:

**can we use *"can", "could", "may" & "might"* to ask for suggestions"?**

Answer (score 1):

The rule children are taught is that "***can***" implies ability and "***may***" asks for permission

> Q: **Can** I have dessert now?
>   A: Yes you **can**, but you **may** not.

In terms of a suggestion, it depends more on how your question is worded and also the context surrounding the question.  If you are coming into the house laden with groceries, you might ask

> Where **shall** I put the vegetables?
>   Where **can** I put the vegetables?
>   Where **may** I put the vegtables?
>   Where **might** I put the vegetables? *(this one is a little stylized)*

All basically mean

> Where do you want the vegetables to be put?

The hard and fast rules you cite, really aren't so hard and fast.

**Could** and **should** might be used to ask for suggestions

> What **could** it possibly mean?
>   **Should** I be formal or casual?