# How can I use "can" with negation words (such as "can ... not") instead of antonym verbs?

Tags: modal-verbs, negation

In the following sentence:

> They can disagree.

what I want to say is that the subject, ***they***, can possibly reach a state when they no longer ***agree***. Of course, it can be the opposite - they can agree with each other and live happily ever after, but I'd like to specifically underline the chance for the negative outcome. So what I did is I took an antonym for verb "agree", ***disagree***, and this was all I needed to build this very simple sentence. So far so good.

But what if I have a verb that doesn't have a simple antonym (or I just forgot this antonym and I need to come up quickly with a grammatical construct to compensate this)? Such as ***negotiate***. Obviously, I can't say "they can not negotiate", because in English, "X can not Y" doesn't mean "X can possibly reach a state when X doesn't Y". It means "X won't do Y, never ever". But what should I do, then?

I can probably put a filler word between "can" and "not" to break this pattern, such as:

> They can possibly not negotiate. / They can possibly not agree.

But is it correct, is it idiomatic English?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can we use "can", "could", "may" & "might" to ask for suggestions"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177140/can-we-use-can-could-may-might-to-ask-for-suggestions) Also [Can vs May (Which one is correct?)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/201884/can-vs-may-which-one-is-correct), and probably several others.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "can" with "may". "They may not agree".

Wow, that was such a simple problem and I thought it was worthy to ask. So sorry :) I will delete this question if requested.

Comment: *Might* would be a little better, only because *may* is used to indicate permission - so it's possible that "they may not agree" could mean "they are allowed to not agree" in the sense that someone is saying that is an OK outcome.